# What is the correct approach to marking up HTML5 footer content?

Tags: css, html, footer, markup

Currently working on a site template rebuild in HTML5 and with trying to keep in line with semantic best practices the markup is getting completely bloated with divs for what I would deem non page relevant content. Here's the markup I'm currently working with for a rather large page footer block containing various info panels:

```
<footer class="container">
    <div class="footer-info-panel left">
        <div class="contact-details">
            <div class="heading">Contact Us</div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="follow-us">
            <div class="heading">Follow Us</div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bookmark">
            <div class="heading">Bookmark &amp; Recommend Us</div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-info-panel right">
        <div class="payment-methods">
            <div class="heading">Payment Methods</div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="customer-services">
            <div class="heading">Customer Services</div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="company-info">
            <div class="heading">Company Information</div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

So adhering to OOCSS techniques in SASS with minimal stylesheet nesting I can simply define global footer styles as .footer-info-panel .heading { *styles here* } etc, however should I be using one of the h1-h6 tags, it seems like div overkill yet my interpretation of the the html5 spec would say otherwise as it's not relevant page content?

Comment: You got *`section, aside, article, nav, navgroup, header`*. For instance, those two `footer-info-panel`s could be `aside`s.

Comment: Could do but the footer intrinsically holds enough semantic difference to 'separate' the info blocks from the page content?

Comment: Looks like you got a [group of nav elements](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/aside). Intrinsic? Who knows. Is your question whether `h1` tags in a footer aren't intrinsically semantic?

Comment: The examples on [the W3 `footer` page](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/footer) include a `nav` and some `p` tags within it.

Answer (score 1):

[Straight from the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element):

> Some site designs have what is sometimes referred to as "fat footers"
>   — footers that contain a lot of material, including images, links to
>   other articles, links to pages for sending feedback, special offers...
>   in some ways, a whole "front page" in the footer.
>
> This fragment shows the bottom of a page on a site with a "fat
>   footer":

```
...
 <footer>
  <nav>
   <section>
    <h1>Articles</h1>
    <p><img src="images/somersaults.jpeg" alt=""> Go to the gym with
    our somersaults class! Our teacher Jim takes you through the paces
    in this two-part article. <a href="articles/somersaults/1">Part
    1</a> · <a href="articles/somersaults/1">Part 2</a></p>
    <p><img src="images/kindplus.jpeg"> Tired of walking on the edge of
    a clif<!-- sic -->? Our guest writer Lara shows you how to bumble
    your way through the bars. <a href="articles/kindplus/1">Read
    more...</a></p>
    <p><img src="images/crisps.jpeg"> The chips are down, now all
    that's left is a potato. What can you do with it? <a
    href="articles/crisps/1">Read more...</a></p>
   </section>
   <ul>
    <li> <a href="/about">About us...</a>
    <li> <a href="/feedback">Send feedback!</a>
    <li> <a href="/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <p><small>Copyright © 2015 The Snacker —
  <a href="/tos">Terms of Service</a></small></p>
 </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Good find... It feels as if I'm on a go kart track here. Reading the nav spec, "the footer element alone is sufficient for such cases; while a nav element can be used in such cases, it is usually unnecessary."

Comment: Re your h1 q above I guess I'm also taking into account the current state of SEO indexing and how widely it's supported. If we're putting h1 in a footer element, and six of them, I certainly wouldn't want as much importance placed on them as the content title. Just had a read of html5doc [document outlines](http://html5doctor.com/outlines/) and the w3 spec which says, "Make available to the user an "outline" view of rendered content, composed of labels for important structural elements (e.g., heading text, table titles, form titles, and other labels that are part of the content)."

Comment: ... and in this case I wouldn't really consider the actual footer content 'important structural elements' relative to the main page content.

Comment: I'm thinking if it's not in a `section`ing block, it's outside of the content context within the page and (perhaps) should be excluded from any content decisions. Logically, I think they've given more latitude than that, especially with HTML5 (which is loosy-goosy compared to XHTML). With what you have above though, you might possibly use a `dl`, which fits the format of the `footer` content, and wrap with a `nav`.

Answer (score 0):

As Jared you may use the `aside` or `section` elements.

Comment: The spec states, "The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline."  

With that in mind and given the footer info panels/blocks aren't relevant to the focal point of the page content as a whole it wouldn't make sense to have them listed in the document outline.

Comment: `section` and `article` seem a bit of a stretch getting down to brass tacks.